# My methods aren't being used. Value is not a function

Tags: actionscript-3, function

I'm making a simple player vs ai tic tac toe game, but for some reason, the game does not work. The ai does not run and the player can continue to place x on the playing board. The game does not end or show any sign of ending when the player "wins".

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var BoardArray = new Array(TL, TC, TR, ML, MC, MR, BL, BC, BR)
var Humanturn:Boolean = true;
var Win:Boolean = false;

var Playerscore = 0;
var Computerscore = 0;
var Turns = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < BoardArray.length; i++)
{
    BoardArray[i].stop();
    BoardArray[i].buttonMode = true;
    BoardArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, BoxClicked);
}

function BoxClicked(e:MouseEvent)
{
    if (Win != true && Humanturn == true && e.target.currentFrame == 1)
    {
        e.target.gotoAndStop(2);
        CheckWin();
        Turns++;
        if (Turns == 5)
        {
            Win = true;
            gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 4");
        }
        else
        {
            AIMove();
        }
    }
    if (Win == true)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < BoardArray.length; j++)
        {
            BoardArray[j].gotoAndStop(1);
        }
        Win = false;
        Turns = 0;
    }
}

function AIMove():void
{
    var AIPosition = RndNum(8)
    if (Win == false)
    {
        if (BoardArray[AIPosition].currentFrame == 1)
        {
            BoardArray[AIPosition].gotoAndStop(3);
            CheckWin();
        }
        else
        {
            AIMove();
        }
    }
}

function CheckWin():void
{         // Check for Horizontal Win
    if ( (TL.currentFrame == 2 && TC.currentFrame == 2 && TR.currentFrame == 2)
         (ML.currentFrame == 2 && MC.currentFrame == 2 && MR.currentFrame == 2)
         (BL.currentFrame == 2 && BC.currentFrame == 2 && BR.currentFrame == 2)
          // Check for Vertical Win
         (TL.currentFrame == 2 && ML.currentFrame == 2 && BL.currentFrame == 2)
         (TC.currentFrame == 2 && MC.currentFrame == 2 && BC.currentFrame == 2)
         (TR.currentFrame == 2 && MR.currentFrame == 2 && BR.currentFrame == 2)
          // Check for Diagonal Win
         (TL.currentFrame == 2 && MC.currentFrame == 2 && BR.currentFrame == 2)
         (TR.currentFrame == 2 && MC.currentFrame == 2 && BL.currentFrame == 2) )

    {
        Playerscore++;
        Player.text = "Player: " + Playerscore;
        Win = true;
    }         // Check for AI Horizontal Win
    else if ((TL.currentFrame == 3 && TC.currentFrame == 3 && TR.currentFrame == 3)
         (ML.currentFrame == 3 && MC.currentFrame == 3 && MR.currentFrame == 3)
         (BL.currentFrame == 3 && BC.currentFrame == 3 && BR.currentFrame == 3)
          // Check for AI Vertical Win
         (TL.currentFrame == 3 && ML.currentFrame == 3 && BL.currentFrame == 3)
         (TC.currentFrame == 3 && MC.currentFrame == 3 && BC.currentFrame == 3)
         (TR.currentFrame == 3 && MR.currentFrame == 3 && BR.currentFrame == 3)
          // Check for AI Diagonal Win
         (TL.currentFrame == 3 && MC.currentFrame == 3 && BR.currentFrame == 3)
         (TR.currentFrame == 3 && MC.currentFrame == 3 && BL.currentFrame == 3) )
    {
        Computerscore++;
        Computer.text = "Computer: " + Computerscore;
        Win = true;
    }
}

function RndNum(Numm):uint
{
    return Math.round(Math.random() * Numm)
}
```

Any idea what's going on?
Thanks

Comment: You're missing quite a few `||`'s in `CheckWin`.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions of winning are not good, try to add || (or) between conditions.

Ex:

```
if (   (TL.currentFrame == 2 && TC.currentFrame == 2 && TR.currentFrame == 2) ||
     (ML.currentFrame == 2 && MC.currentFrame == 2 && MR.currentFrame == 2) ||
     (BL.currentFrame == 2 && BC.currentFrame == 2 && BR.currentFrame == 2) ||
      // Check for Vertical Win
     (TL.currentFrame == 2 && ML.currentFrame == 2 && BL.currentFrame == 2) ||
     (TC.currentFrame == 2 && MC.currentFrame == 2 && BC.currentFrame == 2) ||
     (TR.currentFrame == 2 && MR.currentFrame == 2 && BR.currentFrame == 2) ||
      // Check for Diagonal Win
     (TL.currentFrame == 2 && MC.currentFrame == 2 && BR.currentFrame == 2) ||
     (TR.currentFrame == 2 && MC.currentFrame == 2 && BL.currentFrame == 2) )

{
    trace( 'playerwin' );
}
```

PS: try use capital letters on begin of word only for class names and use lowercase start letters for variables. It's more clear for everyone ;) (ex: MyClassName, myVarName)

Comment: Alright, will do. I'm new to as3 and I'm still struggling with its syntax. Are there any other mistakes you might have spotted?